# how do i set data and index into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql

i have query like this

```
test = spark.sql("select mg.moviegenreid, sum(quantity) as total \
                from moviegenre mg \
                join movie m on m.moviegenreid = mg.moviegenreid \
                join detailtransaction dt on dt.movieid = m.movieid \
                join headertransaction ht on ht.transactionid = dt.transactionid \
                group by mg.moviegenreid \
                having sum(quantity) \
                order by total desc \
                limit 5")
```

then I inserted it into pandas dataframe

```
data = test.toPandas()
```

i just want to make barline using

```
x = data[{"moviegenreid"}]
y = data[{"total"}
val = pd.DataFrame(data=y,index=x)
val.plot.bar()
```

I always get errors like this

```
ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{Try:

```
x = data["moviegenreid"]
y = data["total"]
val = pd.DataFrame({'data'=y},index=x)
val.plot.bar()
```

Comment: Its work perfectly, but how, is that any different data[{"moviegenreid"}] with data["moviegenreid"]. thank you so much :)